# Is there such a thing as a Google Result Set simulator?

Tags: seo

I am always making tweaks to my site, be it in the .htaccess file, some new SEO plugin, different types of content or whatever.

For all these changes, I would really like to be able test it immediately and see if the change had any positive or negative effect.

I am just wondering if there was some way of doing immediate testing using some simulator instead of having to wait for Google to discover and index it - which could take a long time.

Comment: You'd have to know Google's algorithm to do this. Naturally only Google knows this so the answer would be "no".

Comment: Google's actually pretty quick these days. But in partial answer to your question, if such a tool did exist (and was officially by Google), black-hatters would try to misuse it to promote their sites illegitimately. While Google wants sites to be comprehensible and semantic, they don't want sites to be designed for search engines.

Answer (score 1):

There is no preview for regular results. Google uses many factors for the display of the SER. It may use a snippet of the page, or the `meta` `description`, or the ODP description. It may use the full actual `title` of the page or a manipulated one. It may add anchor links. And so on.

For **Rich Snippets** (RDFa, microdata, microformats) there is a SER preview: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

For **AdWords** there is a preview of the SERP (however, it uses the real data, so only for already indexed pages): https://adwords.google.com/d/AdPreview/